# What is the solution to this overfull \hbox error?

Tags: errors, compilation-error

This is my code

```
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Let there be 2 points.$z_{0}$ and $z_{0}^{\prime}$ in a \textit{\textbf{ complex plane(contour) }}.We divide the contour from $z_{0}$ to $z_{0}^{\prime}$ as designated path C,in \textbf{n} intervals by picking \textbf{n-1} intermediate points as $z_{1} , z_{2} , z_{3} \dots$ on the contour.\\
so the sum\\
{\Large$s_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{j})(z_{j}-z_{j-1})$}\\
where$\zeta_{j}$ is a point on the curve between $z_{j}  \quad and  \quad z_{j-1}$(a small part of the curve).\\
now let's $n \rightarrow \infty \quad and  \quad |z_{j} - z_{j-1}| \rightarrow 0$ for all j.\\
if {\Large$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_{n}  \quad exists$}, then \\
{\Large$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{j})(z_{j}-z_{j-1})=\int_{z_{0}}^{z_{0}^{\prime}}f(z)dz = \int_{C}f(z)dz$}\\
It can also be defined as \\
\begin{align*}
\int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}}f(z)dz &= \int_{x_{1}y_{1}}^{x_{2}y_{2}}[u(x,y) + iv(x,y)][dx + idy]\\
 &= \int_{x_{1}y_{1}}^{x_{2}y_{2}}[u(x,y)dx - v(x,y)dy] + i \int_{x_{1}y_{1}}^{x_{2}y_{2}}[v(x,y)dx + u(x,y)dy]\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting this error.
**Overfull \hbox (1.60175pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--17**.
How to solve it?
EDIT: Now it's solved and I have edited the code to be correct.

Comment: your code can not be run as posted. If I add `\documentclass{article}` it does not make an overfull box warning it makes a (more serious) underfull box badness 10000 warning due to mis-use of `\\ ` and a fatal `! Double superscript.` error  due to two `^` on the same base. Please edit the question to have an example of the problem you are asking for help with (it is not an error just a line that is too long to fit on the page)

Answer (score 2):

If I add `\documentclass{book}` to the top of your code, I get the following output:

[image]

I'm sorry to say that it's a specimen of very bad typography.

In line 1 punctuation is inconsistent; “2 points” should be “two points”.

In line 2 boldface n and n-1 should be in math italic.

In line 3, a comma should precede the three dots.

The display on line 5 is as horrible as it can be: there is no need whatsoever for making the formula larger. The same for the following display.

Fixing these points will make the overfull vanish.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Let there be two points $z_{0}$ and $z'_{0}$ in a \textit{\textbf{complex plane (contour)}}.
We divide the contour from $z_{0}$ to $z'_{0}$ as designated path $C$, in~$n$ intervals 
by picking $n-1$ intermediate points $z_{1}$, $z_{2}$, $z_{3}$,\dots\ on the contour so the sum
\[
s_{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{j})(z_{j}-z_{j-1})
\]
where $\zeta_{j}$ is a point on the curve between $z_{j}$ and $z_{j-1}$ 
(a small part of the curve).

Now let $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $|z_{j} - z_{j-1}| \rightarrow 0$, for all~$j$.

If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_{n}$ exists, then
\[
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{j})(z_{j}-z_{j-1})=
\int_{z_{0}}^{z'_{0}} f(z)\,dz = \int_{C}f(z)\,dz
\]
It can also be defined as
\begin{align*}
\int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}}f(z)\,dz
&= \int_{x_{1}y_{1}}^{x_{2}y_{2}}[u(x,y) + iv(x,y)][dx + i\,dy] \\
&= \int_{x_{1}y_{1}}^{x_{2}y_{2}}[u(x,y)\,dx - v(x,y)\,dy]
  + i \int_{x_{1}y_{1}}^{x_{2}y_{2}}[v(x,y)\,dx + u(x,y)\,dy]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Fixing also the language:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Let us be given two points two points $z_{0}$ and $z'_{0}$ on a \emph{contour} in 
the complex plane. We divide the contour from $z_{0}$ to $z'_{0}$, denoted as the path~$C$,
in~$n$ intervals by picking $n-1$ intermediate points $z_{1}$, $z_{2}$, $z_{3}$,\dots\ 
on the contour and define the sum
\[
s_{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{j})(z_{j}-z_{j-1})
\]
where $\zeta_{j}$ is a point on the curve between $z_{j}$ and $z_{j-1}$ 
(a small part of the curve).

Now let $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $|z_{j} - z_{j-1}| \rightarrow 0$, for all~$j$.

If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_{n}$ exists, then
\[
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f(\zeta_{j})(z_{j}-z_{j-1})=
\int_{z_{0}}^{z'_{0}} f(z)\,dz = \int_{C}f(z)\,dz
\]
The integral can also be defined as
\begin{align*}
\int_{z_{1}}^{z_{2}}f(z)\,dz
&= \int_{x_{1}y_{1}}^{x_{2}y_{2}}[u(x,y) + iv(x,y)][dx + i\,dy] \\
&= \int_{x_{1}y_{1}}^{x_{2}y_{2}}[u(x,y)\,dx - v(x,y)\,dy]
  + i \int_{x_{1}y_{1}}^{x_{2}y_{2}}[v(x,y)\,dx + u(x,y)\,dy]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
It appears that there was a double superscript causing this error.
Sorry for asking without double/triple checking.
Won't happen again.

Comment: the double superscript causes a double superscript error it doesn't generate an overfull hbox warning. (with article class you don't get that warning at all, perhaps with other classes the typeset output if you scroll past that error might, but its not really related to the error)

Comment: didn't know about that. I noticed it's still present in the console output but it's not causing the complication error anymore

Comment: yes of course the `^^` error is an _error_ but the error message is `! Double superscript`  The over and underfull box warnings are warnings and do not stop the run (but you should still fix them) the title of your post is asking about the overfull box warning. So this answer is confusing for future readers  The underfull box warnings are from `\\ ` never use `\\ ` before display math or at the end of a paragraph.